# How to get JSON data value based on another value on the same level?

Tags: json, google-places-api, pentaho, kettle, jsonpath

I am trying to parse Google Places JSON provided when I call its API. My Problem is that I need to get address data in separate.

For example:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "48",
            "short_name" : "48",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Pirrama Road",
            "short_name" : "Pirrama Road",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Pyrmont",
            "short_name" : "Pyrmont",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "NSW",
            "short_name" : "NSW",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "AU",
            "short_name" : "AU",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "2009",
            "short_name" : "2009",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         }
      ], ......
```

I need to get the `postal_code`, so I could use the Jason Path `$.result.address_components[5].long_name`, but sometimes the Json doesn't have the `street_number`, or the `route` and in these cases, I get the wrong data or `null`.

What I need is a way to get the `long_name` where the level's type is `postal_code` using `Xpath` (because I using Pentaho to parse it and this is the way it works).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: XPath is for XML documents, not JSON.  Are you converting this JSON to XML in some manner?

Comment: @MikeBrant I am not converting. I am using a Xpath-like for Json

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely need a couple of JSON Input steps, one to get the individual address components (and the types inside), and one to get the long_name:

[image]

The Filter Rows step will pick the right one(s) by type, then the last JSON Input will get you the fields from the one(s) you want. Here's a Gist with your sample input:

https://gist.github.com/mattyb149/0ceea5d7e33ae86782e0

Let me know if you have any questions, issues, etc.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am not sure if I understood what you did. Could you post the pictures of these steps properties?

Comment: I am asking you that because I need to get all addresses. For those that has the postal code, I need to get it into a separate excel column at the end. For those that hasn't, then null. Think this won't be a problem, but I didn't understand what you did. Think this might work and just need some clarification. :)

Comment: If you go to the gist, download it, and open it in PDI, you can see all the step dialogs' settings